# Nodejs server stopping

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

I have a server on Amazon Ec2 (m1.large) running ExpressJS/Nodejs. this my server receive 2.000 requests per second, but nodejs after a time is stopping alone.. showing in my browser "This webpage is not available".. the nodejs not support a couple of requests? or it can be my  server configuration?

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var mysql   = require('mysql');
var routes  = require('./routes');
var verify  = require('./routes/verify');
var http    = require('http');
var path    = require('path');






pool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'rds.amazonaws.com', //old db
  user     : '123123',
  password : '123123',
  database : '123'
});



var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080); //3000, 8080
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}



app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/l.node', verify.checkin); //l.cpp?q=31&w=c
app.get('/crossdomain.xml', verify.crossdomain); 

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('@Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));

});
```

verify.js

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CROSSDOMAIN.XML
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
exports.crossdomain = function (req, res){

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
  res.send('<?xml version="1.0"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" /></cross-domain-policy>');

};





















/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BANNER CHECK-IN
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
exports.checkin = function(req, res){
    banner_id = req.query.q;
    type_req  = req.query.w;






        updateBannerView(banner_id, type_req, true);


        if(type_req == 'c'){
            updateBannerClick( banner_id, res);
        } else {
            res.send('commit range ' + banner_id + '..' + type_req + '; l:');
        }






}; //end exposts













/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ADD CLICK BANNER
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
var updateBannerClick = function (p_banner_id, p_res) {
    var link = '';

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {


    connection.query("UPDATE  `reportbanners` SET  `clicks` = `clicks`+1 WHERE `date` = ? AND `banner_id` = ?", [getDateTime(), p_banner_id], 
        function(err,rows,field){
     });

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM  `banners` WHERE  `id` = ?', [p_banner_id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(rows.length != 0){
            link = rows[0].banner_clicklink;
            p_res.send('<script>window.location = "' + link + '";</script>');
            console.log("Link Active");
        } else {
            console.log("Error Link Active");
            p_res.send('<script>window.location = "http://www.google.com.br";</script>');
        }

    });


    connection.release();
  });//end pool


};















/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ADD VIEW BANNER
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
var updateBannerView = function (p_banner_id, p_type_req, p_isSessionViewUpdate) {
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

            console.log(err);
    var getQuery = "";
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM  `reportbanners` WHERE  `date` = ? AND `banner_id` = ?', [getDateTime(), p_banner_id], function(err, rows, fields) {


      if(rows.length == 0){



        if(p_isSessionViewUpdate){
            getQuery = "INSERT INTO `reportbanners` (`id` , `date` , `clicks` , `views` , `session_views` , `banner_id` ) VALUES (NULL ,  NOW(),  '0',  '1',  '1',  ?)";
        } else {
            getQuery = "INSERT INTO `reportbanners` (`id` , `date` , `clicks` , `views` , `session_views` , `banner_id` ) VALUES (NULL ,  NOW(),  '0',  '1',  '0',  ?)";
        }

        connection.query(getQuery, [p_banner_id], 
            function(err,rows,field){

            });
        // debug
        console.log("INSERT REG");




      } else {




        if(p_isSessionViewUpdate){
            getQuery = "UPDATE  `reportbanners` SET  `views` = `views`+1, `session_views` = `session_views`+1 WHERE `date` = ? AND `banner_id` = ?";
        } else {
            getQuery = "UPDATE  `reportbanners` SET  `views` = `views`+1 WHERE `date` = ? AND `banner_id` = ?";
        }

        connection.query(getQuery, [getDateTime(), p_banner_id], 
            function(err,rows,field){

            });

        console.log("ATT REG");



      };






      console.log('Results: ', rows.length);
      console.log('date: ', getDateTime());


      // console.log('s: ', the_banner_link);
    });





connection.release();
});//end pool
};









var getDateTime = function () {

    var date = new Date();

    var hour = date.getHours();
    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

    var min  = date.getMinutes();
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    var sec  = date.getSeconds();
    sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;

    var day  = date.getDate();
    day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;

    // return year + ":" + month + ":" + day + ":" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

}
```

Comment: You really need to add more information for anyone to come up with anything useful for you. NodeJS should be capable of serving thousands even 10s of thousands of requests. Posting actually error log and perhaps the code of your nodejs/express implmementation would be highly beneficial so SO users could troubleshoot your situation more accurately.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you logging anything? Are you able to reproduce this problem on your development machine?

Comment: No, without error.. my err.log is empty..

Comment: Take a look in my code

Comment: Hi everyone, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that:

(1) **You are invoking your node app from a terminal and the app is killed when the terminal is closed. Or**

(2) Your script may be failing at some point in time. Or

(3) Your server is rebooted.

Solutions for each case:

(1) Use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). `nohup node server.js &`

(2) Run your app with [forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/). `forever start server.js`

(3) Configure your system to run your app when the system is booted. Eg. using [upstart](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/)

Comment: I alright was using everything above.. but no success.. I'm trying it: ulimit -n 188898 until now work for me, but I can to confirm only tomorrow. thank you and tomorrow I post feedback..